# Android : SharedPreferences in BroadcastReceiver RadioButton's integer value do not update?

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist

I have Activity to change the radioButton.

in oncreate Method

```
     sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
     radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener);
```

Implement the overridden method and get the Radiobutton save  the sharedpreference

```
 RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener =
          new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

         RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
         int checkedIndex = radioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);

         savePreferences("remaindertype_toggle_value",checkedIndex);
         Log.e("Chenge", String.valueOf(checkedIndex)); // here the get proper value of checkdIndex  
            }};
```

Implement the sharePreference method...

```
private void savePreferences(String key, int data) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();     
    editor.putInt(key, data);               
    editor.commit();        
    Log.e("Chengeinside", String.valueOf(value));// Here also get the proper value of the data..
     }
```

now when the Receive the AlarmReceiver extend BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =         
                      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    TypeToggleValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(RemainderType_Toggle, 0);

        Log.e("AppToggleValue", String.valueOf(TypeToggleValue));// here when first  time run the application get the proper value but change the value and secound time get the value its does not updated

 }
```

I am also maintain the AndroidMainifest.xml file

```
  <receiver 
        android:name="AlarmReceiver" 
        android:process=":remote"
           />
```

The issue is in onReceive.. the first time the "checkedIndex" field is correct. The second time, if checkedIndex is updated when radioButton change , however, it returns the first value. The value does not seem to get updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here AndroidMainifest.xml in the file change the receiver value...

```
 <receiver 
    android:name="AlarmReceiver" 
            />
```